# Any functional way to retrive data from array and object?

Tags: kotlin

I am doing this as shown below
was wonder if there is any better functional way of fetching data from object and array

```
data.description = session.product?.informations?.get(0)?.levels?.details?.get(0)?.description
```

Comment: What do you mean by "functional"? Your code is merely a traversing through properties, so you can't really skip it. Do you mean that e.g. only a `product` could be null, all other are non-null, but you still need to use `?.` everywhere? Also, please note that your code will throw `NoSuchElementException` if `informations` or `details` are empty. You can use `getOrNull()` to avoid that.

Comment: doesn't it look bit ugly? one way i could think was to use ```also``` but that doesn't change. any other way ?

Comment: I don't really know, what do you mean exactly. Do you mean it's ugly that in Kotlin we need to explicitly specify, what to do with nulls (`?.`)? Do you mean that we need to replace simple `[0]` with `?.get(0)`?

Comment: Sometimes, we have a long chain of calls/props where only the first one is nullable and the rest is not-null. Then it may feel a little awkward or ugly that we need to put `?.` everywhere through a chain. If this is your case, you can write it as: `session.product?.let { it.informations[0].levels.details[0].description`. It is a matter of taste if this is better or not.

Comment: All those null checks are bad.